# Adding missing road lines to base data using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing, road

I have a master base road dataset, in the attached picture they are red lines. A second dataset of roads needs to be added (yellow lines), but only where we are missing a road. The two datasets overlap but not identically in most places so doing a select by location on identical and then inverting the selection doesn't work.

I know some of this process will need to be manual where the incoming data is similar to the existing data but is far enough away/different enough to need manual assessment if the incoming data is better/worse quality than the existing master data, but for a lot of the data the two are 'close enough' that i can ignore the new incoming and retain the existing.

It is when there is a yellow line that extends beyond a red line, or where there is a yellow line with no overlap (coincident or not) with the red line that I am trying to identify for adding to the master data.

The amount of data is quite large so I am trying to find a way to minimize the amount of manual work involved.

How do I select just the 'missing' yellow linework to add it to the red master data using ArcGIS Pro?

If this were Photoshop I'd make the red linework thicker to cover all underlying yellow, then do a 'select by colour' on yellow and get any yellow that is sticking out from underneath the red.

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to do it in ArcPro but you could look at hausdorff distance.  You could do an intersection and test for a percentage of overlap.  You could select the yellow lines that only have point intersections and no line intersections.  Just some random thoughts.

Comment: You might look at the Erase tool.  You could buffer your red lines a small amount to create a polygon layer sufficient to cover most of the new lines, then use that to erase lines it overlaps.  You likely would want to run an extend line tool or snap tool to connect the remaining lines to the original.

Comment: @John Looks like an answer to me, I was thinking about this approach myself.

Comment: So to paraphrase @John's suggestion to make sure I understand: 1) I buffer the Base Roads maybe 2m/side, 2) use this buffered polygon with the Erase tool and apply it to the New Roads dataset to remove most existing Base Roads from the New Roads dataset, 3) select remaining New Roads and copy/paste those into Base Roads, 4) run Extend Line tool on still-selected newly pasted Base Roads imported records to add ~2m to them so they connect to the existing Base Road records, 5) run a Snap process on the whole Base Roads dataset to clean up the intersections and make coincident. Is that a workflow?